# Log Data on Windows Phone, transfer to Development Machine later

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'd like store data being retrieved during execution of program on the Windows phone. During execution, the phone is not connected to development machine.

After having enough data (GPS-Data), I'd like to Transfer the log file to development machine, where I can analyze the data to improve the application.

This use-case is only relevant during development and not for the end-user.

Is there a mechanism in Windows Phone 7.5 SDK implemented that I can Transfer data from Isolated Storage simply to development machine or do I have to upload it to Microsoft SkyDrive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Windows Phone Power Tools to easily browse the contents of the isolated storage and transfer files to your computer: http://wptools.codeplex.com/